# SQL Server Management Studio 17.2 "cannot find one or more..."

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a known problem "cannot find one or more components"

I tried to reinstall it, I tried to search in regedit: "SQL Server Management Studio" to delete the "config", but I didn't found that folder.

After that I saw in Programs an Features Visual Studio Shell 2015(isolated) but when I click on modify it gives me an windows with text "bla, bla, Net. Framework required" and I click on "Accept and Install" and after 1-2 secs the window close itself. I have installed required Net. Frameworks.

And then I tried to install softs from redist folder but one of them gives me the windows with text "bla, bla, Net. Framework Required" and I only can close the windows.

What can I do with that?

Comment: It looks like other people have had this issue with previous versions as well. I would take a look at this answer over at the [Database Administrators Page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111450/cannot-find-one-or-more-components-please-reinstall-the-application#111451)

Comment: @ikaikastine, I found that answer before but I don't even have installed this version of visual studio shell. I tried to install it but I have same trouble

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have any constructive answer here. I'm just disappointed that this SSDT / SSMS / Visual Studio fiasco is continuing.

Comment: All these things have an install log - I don't know where it is you'll have to google for it. But you might find a more useful error there. Unfortunately when you google that you'll probably find the usual array of wild guesses and unhelpful suggestions